# How to filter rows of Pandas dataframe by checking whether sub-level index value within a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample Pandas dataframe `df` which has multi_level index:

```
>>> df
                STK_Name   ROIC   mg_r
STK_ID RPT_Date                       
002410 20111231      ???  0.401  0.956
300204 20111231      ???  0.375  0.881
300295 20111231     ????  2.370  0.867
300288 20111231     ????  1.195  0.861
600106 20111231     ????  1.214  0.857
300113 20111231     ????  0.837  0.852
```

and `stk_list` is defined as `stk_list = ['600106','300204','300113']`

I want to get the rows of `df` whose value of sub_level index `STK_ID` is within `stk_list` . The output is as below:

```
                STK_Name   ROIC   mg_r
STK_ID RPT_Date                       
300204 20111231      ???  0.375  0.881
600106 20111231     ????  1.214  0.857
300113 20111231     ????  0.837  0.852
```

Basically, I can achieve the target for this sample data by:

```
df = df.reset_index() ; df[df.STK_ID.isin(stk_list)]
```

But I already have columns 'STK_ID' & 'RPT_Date' in my application dataframe, so reset_index() will cause an error. Anyway, I want to directly filter against index instead of columns.

Learn from this : [How to filter by sub-level index in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224778/how-to-filter-by-sub-level-index-in-pandas)

I try `df[df.index.map(lambda x: x[0].isin(stk_list))]` , and Pandas 0.8.1 gives `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'isin'`,

My question:  How should I filter rows of Pandas dataframe by checking whether sub-level index value within a list without using the `reset_index()` & `set_index()` methods?

Comment: `df[df.index.map(lambda x: x[0] in stk_list)]` ?

Comment: @hayden: Well, I guess I should :).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try:

```
df[df.index.map(lambda x: x[0] in stk_list)]
```

Example:

```
In : stk_list
Out: ['600106', '300204', '300113']

In : df
Out:
                STK_Name   ROIC   mg_r
STK_ID RPT_Date
002410 20111231      ???  0.401  0.956
300204 20111231      ???  0.375  0.881
300295 20111231     ????  2.370  0.867
300288 20111231     ????  1.195  0.861
600106 20111231     ????  1.214  0.857
300113 20111231     ????  0.837  0.852

In : df[df.index.map(lambda x: x[0] in stk_list)]
Out:
                STK_Name   ROIC   mg_r
STK_ID RPT_Date
300204 20111231      ???  0.375  0.881
600106 20111231     ????  1.214  0.857
300113 20111231     ????  0.837  0.852
```

Answer (score 11):

How about using the `level` parameter in [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)?

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
            0         1
a 0  0.007288 -0.840392
  1  0.652740  0.597250
b 0 -1.197735  0.822150
  1 -0.242030 -0.655058

In [15]: stk_list = ['a']

In [16]: df.reindex(stk_list, level=0)
Out[16]: 
            0         1
a 0  0.007288 -0.840392
  1  0.652740  0.597250
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty late to the party, but surely the most readable and intuitive way to do this is using `index.levels[n].isin`?

It works like this:

```
>>> stk_list = [600106, 300204, 300113]
>>> df[df.index.levels[0].isin(stk_list)]
                STK_Name   ROIC   mg_r
STK_ID RPT_Date                       
300204 20111231      ???  0.375  0.881
300295 20111231     ????  2.370  0.867
300113 20111231     ????  0.837  0.852
```

What I like about this approach is that the command can virtually be read like an English sentence.

p.s. in the OP, the stk_list is a list of strings. A bit of list comprehension-fu will deal with that:

```
df[df.index.levels[0].isin([int(i) for i in stk_list])]
```

Comment: This did not work for me while       df[df.index.isin(stk_list, .level=0)] did.

Comment: of course the . in front of level is not supposed to be there.

Answer (score 1):

For me it only worked if I take the zero out of the x as follows:

```
a[a.index.map(lambda x: x in b)]
```

Comment: Is this a versioning thing?

Answer (score 0):

`get_level_values`:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values(level = 0).isin(stk_list)]
```