# Slice pandas DataFrame by MultiIndex level or sublevel

Tags: python, pandas

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14964637/2071807) and the lack of an easy answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224778/how-to-filter-by-sub-level-index-in-pandas) I found myself writing a little syntactic sugar to make life easier to filter by MultiIndex level.

```
def _filter_series(x, level_name, filter_by):
    """
    Filter a pd.Series or pd.DataFrame x by `filter_by` on the MultiIndex level
    `level_name`

    Uses `pd.Index.get_level_values()` in the background. `filter_by` is either
    a string or an iterable.
    """
    if isinstance(x, pd.Series) or isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame):
        if type(filter_by) is str:
            filter_by = [filter_by]

        index = x.index.get_level_values(level_name).isin(filter_by)
        return x[index]
    else:
        print "Not a pandas object"
```

But if I know the pandas development team (and I'm starting to, slowly!) there's already a nice way to do this, and I just don't know what it is yet!

Am I right?

Comment: If you are interested in learning more about slicing and filtering multiindex DataFrames, please take a look at my post: [How do I slice or filter MultiIndex DataFrame levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/how-do-i-slice-or-filter-multiindex-dataframe-levels). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I actually upvoted joris's answer... but unfortunately the refactoring he mentions has not happened in 0.14 and is not happening in 0.17 neither. So for the moment let me suggest a quick and dirty solution (obviously derived from Jeff's one):

```
def filter_by(df, constraints):
    """Filter MultiIndex by sublevels."""
    indexer = [constraints[name] if name in constraints else slice(None)
               for name in df.index.names]
    return df.loc[tuple(indexer)] if len(df.shape) == 1 else df.loc[tuple(indexer),]

pd.Series.filter_by = filter_by
pd.DataFrame.filter_by = filter_by
```

... to be used as

```
df.filter_by({'level_name' : value})
```

where `value` can be indeed a single value, but also a list, a slice...

(untested with Panels and higher dimension elements, but I do expect it to work)

Answer (score 5):

This is very easy using the new multi-index slicers in master/0.14 (releasing soon), see [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#multiindexing-using-slicers)

There is an open issue to make this syntatically easier (its not hard to do), see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4036)
e.g something like this: `df.loc[{ 'third' : ['C1','C3'] }]` I think is reasonable

Here's how you can do it (requires master/0.14):

```
In [2]: def mklbl(prefix,n):
   ...:     return ["%s%s" % (prefix,i)  for i in range(n)]
   ...: 


In [11]: index = MultiIndex.from_product([mklbl('A',4),
mklbl('B',2),
mklbl('C',4),
mklbl('D',2)],names=['first','second','third','fourth'])

In [12]: columns = ['value']

In [13]: df = DataFrame(np.arange(len(index)*len(columns)).reshape((len(index),len(columns))),index=index,columns=columns).sortlevel()

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
                           value
first second third fourth       
A0    B0     C0    D0          0
                   D1          1
             C1    D0          2
                   D1          3
             C2    D0          4
                   D1          5
             C3    D0          6
                   D1          7
      B1     C0    D0          8
                   D1          9
             C1    D0         10
                   D1         11
             C2    D0         12
                   D1         13
             C3    D0         14
                   D1         15
A1    B0     C0    D0         16
                   D1         17
             C1    D0         18
                   D1         19
             C2    D0         20
                   D1         21
             C3    D0         22
                   D1         23
      B1     C0    D0         24
                   D1         25
             C1    D0         26
                   D1         27
             C2    D0         28
                   D1         29
             C3    D0         30
                   D1         31
A2    B0     C0    D0         32
                   D1         33
             C1    D0         34
                   D1         35
             C2    D0         36
                   D1         37
             C3    D0         38
                   D1         39
      B1     C0    D0         40
                   D1         41
             C1    D0         42
                   D1         43
             C2    D0         44
                   D1         45
             C3    D0         46
                   D1         47
A3    B0     C0    D0         48
                   D1         49
             C1    D0         50
                   D1         51
             C2    D0         52
                   D1         53
             C3    D0         54
                   D1         55
      B1     C0    D0         56
                   D1         57
             C1    D0         58
                   D1         59
                             ...

[64 rows x 1 columns]
```

Create an indexer across all of the levels, selecting all entries

```
In [15]: indexer = [slice(None)]*len(df.index.names)
```

Make the level we care about only have the entries we care about

```
In [16]: indexer[df.index.names.index('third')] = ['C1','C3']
```

Select it (its important that this is a tuple!)

```
In [18]: df.loc[tuple(indexer),:]
Out[18]: 
                           value
first second third fourth       
A0    B0     C1    D0          2
                   D1          3
             C3    D0          6
                   D1          7
      B1     C1    D0         10
                   D1         11
             C3    D0         14
                   D1         15
A1    B0     C1    D0         18
                   D1         19
             C3    D0         22
                   D1         23
      B1     C1    D0         26
                   D1         27
             C3    D0         30
                   D1         31
A2    B0     C1    D0         34
                   D1         35
             C3    D0         38
                   D1         39
      B1     C1    D0         42
                   D1         43
             C3    D0         46
                   D1         47
A3    B0     C1    D0         50
                   D1         51
             C3    D0         54
                   D1         55
      B1     C1    D0         58
                   D1         59
             C3    D0         62
                   D1         63

[32 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: For clarity, doing this manually on this dataframe would look like `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, :, ['C1','C3'], :], :]` or `df.loc(axis=0)[:,:,['C1','C3'], :]`

Comment: Is there a way to select a date range from a MultiIndex? I have `df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :, :, :, 'value']]` where the first `:` would be a date and I want to slice by a range of dates and not just a single day.

Comment: It also works for Series if you use `s.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, :, ['C1','C3'], :]]` instead of `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, :, ['C1','C3'], :], :]`.

Answer (score 1):

You have the [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) method that can do things like this. Eg with the example that was asked in the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224778/how-to-filter-by-sub-level-index-in-pandas) SO question:

```
In [188]: df.filter(like='0630', axis=0)
Out[188]: 
                      sales        cogs    net_pft
STK_ID RPT_Date                                   
876    20060630   857483000   729541000   67157200
       20070630  1146245000  1050808000  113468500
       20080630  1932470000  1777010000  133756300
2254   20070630   501221000   289167000  118012200
```

The filter method is [refactored](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6599) at the moment (in upcoming 0.14), and a `level` keyword will be added (because now you can have a problem if the same labels appear in different levels of the index).