# Filtering multiple items in a multi-index Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, filtering, multi-index

I have the following table:

```
                               Area
NSRCODE  PBL_AWI          
CM       BONS             44705.492941
         BTNN            253854.591990
         FONG             41625.590370
         FONS             16814.159680
         Lake             57124.819333
         River             1603.906642
         SONS            583958.444751
         STNN             45603.837177
         clearcut        106139.013930
         disturbed       127719.865675
         lowland         118795.578059
         upland         2701289.270193
LBH      BFNN            289207.169650
         BONS           9140084.716743
         BTNI             33713.160390
         BTNN          19748004.789040
         FONG           1687122.469691
         FONS           5169959.591270
         FTNI            317251.976160
         FTNN           6536472.869395
         Lake            258046.508310
         River            44262.807900
         SONS           4379097.677405
         burn regen      744773.210860
         clearcut         54066.756790
         disturbed       597561.471686
         lowland       12591619.141842
         upland        23843453.638117
```

Note: Both `NSRCODE` and `PBL_AWI` are indices.

How do I search for values in column `PBL_AWI`? For example I want to keep the values `['Lake', 'River', 'Upland']`.

Comment: if your table name is df, then df[df['PBL_AWI'] in ['Lake', 'River', 'Upland']],  or df[df['PBL_AWI'] == 'Lake' or df['PBL_AWI'] == ''River or df['PBL_AWI'] == 'Upland'] should do the trick. Filtering is very basic stuff, you should see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html

Comment: @Inox I realize filtering is very basic stuff I have done it before on single index dataframes. However the multi-index dataframe when trying what you have above produces "KeyError: u'no item named PBL_AWI'"

Comment: Though @CTZhu has the right answer, note that you could use a solution like @Inox's by just doing `df = df.reset_index()` first. I often resort to this with a MultiIndex if I can't find a better solution. But I'm finding there usually is a better solution, it's just not very discoverable.

Comment: If you are interested in learning more about slicing and filtering multiindex DataFrames, please take a look at my post: [How do I slice or filter MultiIndex DataFrame levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/how-do-i-slice-or-filter-multiindex-dataframe-levels). Thanks!

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can `get_level_values` in conjunction with Boolean slicing.

```
In [50]:

print df[np.in1d(df.index.get_level_values(1), ['Lake', 'River', 'Upland'])]
                          Area
NSRCODE PBL_AWI               
CM      Lake      57124.819333
        River      1603.906642
LBH     Lake     258046.508310
        River     44262.807900
```

The same idea can be expressed in many different ways, such as `df[df.index.get_level_values('PBL_AWI').isin(['Lake', 'River', 'Upland'])]`

Note that you have `'upland'` in your data instead of `'Upland'`

Comment: I find the second solution useful for a similar problem, selecting rows where multi-index values greater then given number: `df[df.index.get_level_values('level_name') > 1]`.

Comment: 2nd solution should be the answer, clearer and does not require np.

Comment: would be interesting to see what's faster though. np is already a dependency of pandas so hardly a problem.

Answer (score 79):

Another (maybe cleaner) way might be this one:

```
print(df[df.index.isin(['Lake', 'River', 'Upland'], level=1)])
```

The parameter `level` specifies the index number (starting with 0) or index name (here: `level='PBL_AWI'`)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: In this context, where there is already rich discussion of the issues, and if the respondent didn't feel like writing a textbook chapter on the subject, I still find this answer useful.

Comment: Awsome! Using this code, is possible to apply on multiple levels? I want "X" on level 1 and "Y" on level 2.

Comment: I believe you'll need to apply the same code for each level separately (there is no option to write `level=[1,2]` for instance). More details can be found in the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html)

Comment: Yep, @FábioRB, to do this with multiple indices, you'd repeat the pattern, but could still do it in one "line". `df[df.index.isin(['Lake', 'River', 'Upland'], level='PBL_AWI') & df.index.isin(['CM'], level='NSRCODE')]`

Answer (score 26):

A simpler approach using `.loc` would be

```
df.loc[(slice(None),['Lake', 'River', 'Upland']),:]
```

or for Series

```
df.loc[(slice(None),['Lake', 'River', 'Upland'])]
```

`slice(None)` means no filtering on the first level index. We can filter the second level index using a list of values `['Lake', 'River', 'Upland']`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: indices are by definition intended for doing this kind of direct lookup, without needing to create intermediate boolean arrays.

Comment: Did not work for me at first, here is what did: `df.loc[(slice(None), ["Lake", "River", "Upland"]), :]`

Comment: Note that if you provide a single value without a list (i.e. `df.loc[(slice(None),"Lake"]`) it will provide the values without the requested index — which is exactly what I needed to convert the last index values into separated columns !

Comment: What if I wanted to filter by the first level? or by both?

Comment: @GordStephen, yeah, the intermediate boolean array may add a little more overhead (assuming this solution doesn't also do something similar under the hood), but the real advantage of an index is the sorting that allows for rapid search/filter. Some other solutions still take advantage of that and are more intuitive to use, like the one above using `df.index.isin([...], level=...)`. Whereas others remove the index altogether and completely defeat its purpose.

Answer (score 11):

df.**filter(regex=...,axis=...)** is even more succinct, because it works on both index=0 and column=1 axis. You do not need to worry about levels, and you can be lazy with regex. Complete example for filter on index:

```
df.filter(regex='Lake|River|Upland',axis=0)
```

[image]

if you transpose it, and try to filter on columns (axis=1 by default), it works as well:

```
df.T.filter(regex='Lake|River|Upland')
```

[image]

Now, with regex you can also easily fix upper lower case issue with Upland:

```
upland = re.compile('Upland', re.IGNORECASE)
df.filter(regex=upland ,axis=0)
```

[image]

This is the command to read above input table:

`df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(inpute_table), sep="\s{2,}").set_index(['NSRCODE', 'PBL_AWI'])`

Answer (score 9):

Also (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987015/slice-pandas-dataframe-by-multiindex-level-or-sublevel)):

```
def filter_by(df, constraints):
    """Filter MultiIndex by sublevels."""
    indexer = [constraints[name] if name in constraints else slice(None)
               for name in df.index.names]
    return df.loc[tuple(indexer)] if len(df.shape) == 1 else df.loc[tuple(indexer),]

pd.Series.filter_by = filter_by
pd.DataFrame.filter_by = filter_by
```

... to be used as

```
df.filter_by({'PBL_AWI' : ['Lake', 'River', 'Upland']})
```

(untested with Panels and higher dimension elements, but I do expect it to work)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
In [9]: df.query("PBL_AWI == ['Lake', 'River', 'Upland']")
Out[9]: 
                     Area
NSRCODE PBL_AWI          
CM      Lake     57124.82
        River     1603.91
LBH     Lake    258046.51
        River    44262.81
```

However, due to case sensitivity, 'upland' (lower case) won't be found. Therefore I recommend using [`fullmatch`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.fullmatch.html) and set `case=False`:

```
In [10]: df.query("PBL_AWI.str.fullmatch('Lake|River|Upland', case=False).values")
Out[10]: 
                       Area
NSRCODE PBL_AWI            
CM      Lake       57124.82
        River       1603.91
        upland   2701289.27
LBH     Lake      258046.51
        River      44262.81
        upland  23843453.64
```

Answer (score 1):

For simple slicing (for both DataFrames and Series), you can also use `:` to specify that you want all values in that level. For example, we don't care about the value of the first index level in the OP, so we use `:` for it.

```py
df.loc[:, ['Lake', 'upland'], :]
#      ^                         <--- for first index level
#          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      <--- filter for the second index level
#                             ^  <--- select all columns (if any)
```

---

### `pd.IndexSlice[]`

For more complicated slicing, you can use `pd.IndexSlice[]`. For example, if you want to select column(s) as well, then use `pd.IndexSlice[]` to specify which part is the index slicing and which part is column selection.

```py
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, ['Lake', 'upland']], ['Area']]
#                    ^                               <--- slice for first index level
#                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            <--- slice for second index level
#                                             ^^^^   <--- column selection
```

With the input given in the OP, we get the following:

[image: result1]

You can also select by first level, second level and columns as well.

```py
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['CM', ['Lake', 'upland']], ['Area']]
```

[image: result2]

Comment: This is so much more intuitive than using the old `(idx1, slice(None))` style syntax.. For anyone else, documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers)

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to a slight variant of the question asked that might save someone else a little time. If you are looking for a wildcard type match to a label whose exact value you don't know, you can use something like this:

```
q_labels = [ label for label in df.index.levels[1] if label.startswith('Q') ]
new_df = df[ df.index.isin(q_labels, level=1) ]
```