# pandas Conditional update with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have following DataFrame with multiple index on both index and columns.

```
 first   x    y
 second  m    n
A  B
A0 B0    0    0
   B1    0    0
A1 B0    0    0
   B1    0    0
```

I'm trying to update the values with the condition.The condition will be something like:
`rules:

```
[{condition:{'A':'A0,'B':'B0'},value:5},
  {condition:{'B':'B1'},value:3},
 .....]
```

I'm trying to find something that has similar functionality to

- Use `pandas.DataFrame.xs` for **setting** value:

  ```
  for each rule in rules:
      df.xs((conditions.values), level=[conditions.keys]) = value
  ```
- Pass more than one level to `pandas.Index.get_level_values` for setting value:

  ```
  for each rule in rules:
      df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(conditions.keys) == [conditions.values] = value
  ```

The result should be

```
 first   x    y
 second  m    n
A  B
A0 B0    5    5
   B1    3    3
A1 B0    0    0
   B1    3    3`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately selection by `dictionary` in `MultiIndex` in pandas is yet [not supported](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4036), so need custom [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33298422/2901002) adapted for you:

```
rules = [{'condition':{'A':'A0','B':'B0'},'value':5},
         {'condition':{'B':'B1'},'value':3}]

for rule in rules:
    d = rule['condition']
    indexer = [d[name] if name in d else slice(None) for name in df.index.names]
    df.loc[tuple(indexer),] = rule['value']

print (df)
first   x  y
second  m  n
A  B        
A0 B0   5  5
   B1   3  3
A1 B0   0  0
   B1   3  3
```