# Pandas Groupby results coming up based on the value_counts and ascending values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
highest_medals_countries = olympics_merged.groupby(['Sport'])['Team'].value_counts()
highest_medals_countries.sort_values(ascending = False)[:10]
```

**Output**:
    Sport       Team

```
Athletics   United States    3202
            Great Britain    2240
Gymnastics  United States    1939
Swimming    United States    1622
Gymnastics  France           1576
Athletics   France           1494
Gymnastics  Italy            1345
Swimming    Great Britain    1291
Athletics   Germany          1254
Gymnastics  Hungary          1242
```

In the above output, I am stacking the teams with the most number of medals based on sport together but when I look at the output the sports are coming up based on the value counts. How can I get rid of this and put countries together for athletics , Gymnastics, Swimming, etc?

Expected output is:

```
 Sport       Team         
Athletics   United States    3202
            Great Britain    2240
            France           1494
Gymnastics  United States    1939
            France           1576
            Italy            1345
            Hungary          1242
Swimming    United States    1622  
            Great Britain    1291    
Athletics   Germany          1254
```

Comment: just `highest_medals_countries.sum(level=0)`. Or from your original data `olympics_merged['Sport'].value_counts()`.

Comment: But there is also a Team in between. How could you use that and solve the problem.

Comment: What's your expected output *from* the above data?

Comment: I have updated the post. Just check the expected output

Answer (score 0):

By running `sort_values` on your stacked dataframe you force it to sort the entire dataframe by value whereas the values were already sorted within the categories in the first place. So don't run `highest_medals_countries.sort_values(ascending = False)[:10]` and you're fine.

Comment: But if I remove that I get values for all sports. But I need values for specific sports. How can I do it?

Comment: The easiest solution is to drop the rows with the sports you don't need prior to running the groupby. Alternatively you could use one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224545/filtering-multiple-items-in-a-multi-index-python-panda-dataframe) solutions after the groupby.