# "Too many indexers" with DataFrame.loc

Tags: python, pandas

I've read [the docs about slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) a million times, but have never got my head round it, so I'm still trying to figure out how to use `loc` to slice a `DataFrame` with a `MultiIndex`.

I'll start with the `DataFrame` from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22987532/2071807):

```
                           value
first second third fourth       
A0    B0     C1    D0          2
                   D1          3
             C2    D0          6
                   D1          7
      B1     C1    D0         10
                   D1         11
             C2    D0         14
                   D1         15
A1    B0     C1    D0         18
                   D1         19
             C2    D0         22
                   D1         23
      B1     C1    D0         26
                   D1         27
             C2    D0         30
                   D1         31
A2    B0     C1    D0         34
                   D1         35
             C2    D0         38
                   D1         39
      B1     C1    D0         42
                   D1         43
             C2    D0         46
                   D1         47
A3    B0     C1    D0         50
                   D1         51
             C2    D0         54
                   D1         55
      B1     C1    D0         58
                   D1         59
             C2    D0         62
                   D1         63
```

To select just `A0` and `C1` values, I can do:

```
In [26]: df.loc['A0', :, 'C1', :]
Out[26]: 
                           value
first second third fourth       
A0    B0     C1    D0          2
                   D1          3
      B1     C1    D0         10
                   D1         11
```

Which also works selecting from three levels, and even with tuples:

```
In [28]: df.loc['A0', :, ('C1', 'C2'), 'D1']
Out[28]: 
                           value
first second third fourth       
A0    B0     C1    D1          3
             C2    D1          5
      B1     C1    D1         11
             C2    D1         13
```

So far, intuitive and brilliant.

So why can't I select all values from the first index level?

```
In [30]: df.loc[:, :, 'C1', :]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-57b56108d941> in <module>()
----> 1 df.loc[:, :, 'C1', :]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   1176     def __getitem__(self, key):
   1177         if type(key) is tuple:
-> 1178             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1179         else:
   1180             return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
    694 
    695         # no multi-index, so validate all of the indexers
--> 696         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
    697 
    698         # ugly hack for GH #836

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
    125         for i, k in enumerate(key):
    126             if i >= self.obj.ndim:
--> 127                 raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
    128             if not self._has_valid_type(k, i):
    129                 raise ValueError("Location based indexing can only have [%s] "

IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Surely this is not intended behaviour?

*Note: I know this is possible with `df.xs('C1', level='third')` but the current `.loc` behaviour seems inconsistent.*

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is tied to the need to specify the axis of indexing (mentioned in http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html).  An alternative solution to your problem is to simply do this:

```
df.loc(axis=0)[:, :, 'C1', :]
```

Pandas gets confused sometimes when indexes are similar or contain similar values. If you were to have a column named 'C1' or something you would also need to do this under this style of slicing/selecting.

Comment: I actually prefer this answer. It makes `loc` do what (I personally think) it says on the tin. (And certainly makes it do what I want!)

Comment: The odd thing IMO is that you (sometimes) need to specify this even for doing `.loc` indexing on a series, even though there is only one axis.

Answer (score 14):

To be safe (in the sense: this will work in all cases), you need to index both row index and columns, for which you can use `pd.IndexSlice` to do this easily:

```
In [26]: idx = pd.IndexSlice

In [27]: df.loc[idx[:, :, 'C1', :],:]
Out[27]:
                           value
first second third fourth
A0    B0     C1    D0          2
                   D1          3
      B1     C1    D0         10
                   D1         11
A1    B0     C1    D0         18
                   D1         19
      B1     C1    D0         26
                   D1         27
A2    B0     C1    D0         34
                   D1         35
      B1     C1    D0         42
                   D1         43
A3    B0     C1    D0         50
                   D1         51
      B1     C1    D0         58
                   D1         59
```

Here `idx[:, :, 'C1', :]` is an easier way to write `[slice(None), slice(None),'C1', slice(None)]`. Instead of `pd.IndexSlice`, you can also use `np.s_` which is a bit shorter.

The reason that the other ones work, I am not fully sure of. But see the note in the documentation here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers (the first red warning box) where it is stated that:

> You should specify all axes in the `.loc` specifier, meaning the indexer for the index and for the columns. Their are some ambiguous cases where the passed indexer could be mis-interpreted as indexing *both* axes, rather than into say the MuliIndex for the rows.

Comment: This is the first time I've really understood what the section of the docs is going on about.