# IndexingError: Too many indexers while accessing multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe as below.

```
df
Out[209]: 
a       b         
User1   2019-07-01                        [The Milky Way]
        2019-07-02                                    NaN
        2019-07-03                                [Taken]
        2019-07-04                                    NaN
        2019-07-05                          [The Lobster]
        2019-07-06                        [Bloody Sunday]
        2019-07-07                  [Lost in Translation]
        2019-07-08                                    NaN
        2019-07-09                                    NaN
        2019-07-10                             [Face Off]
        2019-07-11                  [The Thief of Bagdad]
        2019-07-12                                    NaN
        2019-07-13                              [Charade]
        2019-07-14                             [Scarface]
        2019-07-15    [Anchorman 2: The Legend Continues]
```

I am trying to access the multiindex, when I access one level, i get the desired output.

```
df.loc['User1']
Out[211]: 
b
2019-07-01                        [The Milky Way]
2019-07-02                                    NaN
2019-07-03                                [Taken]
2019-07-04                                    NaN
2019-07-05                          [The Lobster]
```

But when i am trying the multilevel index accessing, it gives me the error as below.

```
df.loc['User1','2019-07-13']
IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Index looks like this :

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User4', 'User5', 'User6', 'User7', 'User8', 'User9', 'User10'], [2019-07-01, 2019-07-02, 2019-07-03, 2019-07-04, 2019-07-05, 2019-07-06, 2019-07-07, 2019-07-08, 2019-07-09, 2019-07-10, 2019-07-11, 2019-07-12, 2019-07-13, 2019-07-14, 2019-07-15, 2019-07-16, 2019-07-17, 2019-07-18, 2019-07-19, 2019-07-20, 2019-07-21, 2019-07-22, 2019-07-23, 2019-07-24, 2019-07-25, 2019-07-26, 2019-07-27, 2019-07-28, 2019-07-29, 2019-07-30, 2019-07-31, 2019-08-01, 2019-08-02, 2019-08-03, 2019-08-04, 2019-08-05, 2019-08-06, 2019-08-07, 2019-08-08, 2019-08-09, 2019-08-10, 2019-08-11, 2019-08-12, 2019-08-13, 2019-08-14, 2019-08-15, 2019-08-16, 2019-08-17, 2019-08-18, 2019-08-19, 2019-08-20]]
```

How do I get past the error and access the multiindex.

I have found a proposed solution already in another question, but i get the below error.

upon trying the axis = 0 argument, i get the error as `KeyError: ('User1', '2019-07-13')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Too many indexers" with DataFrame.loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781037/too-many-indexers-with-dataframe-loc)

Comment: @FlashThunder want to find a way to access multiindex in my dataframe

Comment: @FlashThunder, upon trying the axis = 0 argument, i get the error as KeyError: ('User1', '2019-07-13')

Answer (score 0):

It looks like:

- *User1* and *2019-07-13* are *MultiIndex* values (with levels named
  *a* and *b*, above respective index columns).
- The variable named *df* is actually a *Series* (your printout has no
  column name, not even the default name like *0*).

Note that `df.loc['User1']` is a case of access to all elements of *df*,
which have *User1* at the first index level.
Your printout contains all existing values at the second MultiIndex level
and corresponding values.

So, if you want to use *loc[...]* with MulitiIndex, specifying values at
**both** levels, then:

- between square brackets should be a **tuple**,
- containing MultiIndex values at consecutive levels.

Then, assuming that *b* column of your MultiIndex is of *string* type, try:

```
df.loc[('User1','2019-07-13')]
```

Another possibility is that *b* is e.g. of *DateTime* type and then you
have to create a variable of *DateTime* type (with proper date) and use
it as the second element of this tuple.

And to check the type of *df* variable, run `type(df)`.

Comment: Running the tuple based command gives me the error as :
KeyError: 'the label [2019-07-02] is not in the [columns]'. I am running it on a Dataframe.

Comment: Pleas provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example of your data. Your question leaves too much unknown details.

Comment: it doesn't look like the OP has a multi-index. Try inspecting df.index and will clearly tell whether you have a multi-index or not.